# When I launch tor browser a pop up says “the tor executable is missing” and won’t let me access tor how do I fix this

Tags: error

When I launch the tor browser a pop up says “ the tor executable is missing” how do I fix to access the web

Answer (score -1):

If it Is linux Os Install through Terminal
If it is windows make sure that virtualization is turned on in BIOS. Or reinstall.